# Save email as .msg in local windows folder using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to save email in my local folder using Excel VBA.

I saw this link https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/361751-vba-saving-email-only-after-send-pushed.html which uses a class module to save the email. It stores the email at the same time it opens it for display. The email saved is the draft email. You can still edit the saved .msg file.

How would I wait until the email is sent? Presumably once it detects the email in the Outlook 'Sent Items' folder?

```
Dim cls_OL As New clsOutlook
Public outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Public Emailpath As String

Sub SendEmail()
Dim objItems As Items
Dim objApp As Object
Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set cls_OL.obj_OL = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = objItems.Add
Emailpath = "V:\test\emailname.msg"
With OutMail
On Error Resume Next
    .HTMLBody = "Hi All, This is test email" 
    .to = "test@test.com"
    .CC = vbnullstring
    .BCC = vbnullstring
    .Subject = "A Subject"
    .Display
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents obj_OL As Outlook.Application

Private Sub obj_OL_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Item.SaveAs Emailpath
  Set obj_OL = Nothing
  Set outMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is the email that is being saved:
[image: Draft Email]

This is what I want to save:
[image: Sent Email]

Edit with the suggestion from Dmitry

```
Dim cls_OL As New clsOutlook
Public outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Public Emailpath As String

Sub SendEmail()
Dim objItems As Items
Dim Emailpath as string
Dim objApp as object
Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objItems = objApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
Set OutMail = objItems.Add 
Emailpath = "V:\test\emailname.msg"
With OutMail

    .HTMLBody = "Hi All, This is test email" 
    .to = "test@test.com"
    .CC = vbnullstring
    .BCC = vbnullstring
    .Subject = "A Subject"
    .Display
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Application

Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Item.SaveAs Emailpath
  Set obj_OL = Nothing
  Set outMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder (you can retrieve it using `Namespace.GetDEfaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)`).

**EDIT**: off the top of my head:

```
public WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items
set objItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
...
Private objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Item.SaveAs Emailpath
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @dmitry,
Thank you for replying. I don't really get what do you mean by listen for it.
Any codes that I need to change. Sorry that I kind of new with Class Module.

Comment: Declare a global Items "with events" (like you do with obj_OL) variable and provide the ItemAdd event handler. Items collection comes from MAPIFolder.Items, and MAPIFolder is retrieved from  Namespace.GetDEfaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

Comment: I am really sorry I don't get what you mean. This is my attempt. I am really sorry because I dont have any background with this. 
Public WithEvents obj_OL As Outlook.Application
Private Sub obj_OL_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Item.ItemAdd Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set obj_OL = Nothing
    Set outMail = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: thank you dmitry. I tried and there is error with the set objItems =Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items said that it is invalid outside procedure. Where should I put it? should be inside my subprocedure in the module?

Comment: I dont know where to put the set objItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items because I put it outside the subprocedure. And it said invalid outside procedure. Where should I put this line?

Comment: You can add it to your SendEmail sub.

Comment: However, there is an error on line 7, please see the edit above.
Set OutMail = cls_OL.objItems.CreateItem(0) ' ERROR HERE

Comment: That line must be Set OutMail = objItems.Add

Comment: Hi @Dmitry. I change it to OutMail=objItems.Add, however, it selected objItems and mentioned variable not defined.

Comment: Did you miss the "Set" keyword? You also need to declare the OutMail variable.

Comment: No I didn't miss the set keyword and I declare outmail like the edited part above.

Comment: The previous line needs to be "Set objItems =Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items"

Comment: It highlighted objItems for this line Set objItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items and mentioned it is not defined.

Comment: Yes, you need to declare (dim) objItems variable.either as Outlook.Items or as a generic Object.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry The code is after i declared Dim objItems as Outlook.Items running, however, nothing happened. I did a debugging and when my cursor go to Set objItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items , the objItems shows ='Nothing'. Is there anything I should do?

Comment: I assumed you added Outlook to your project references? Try to replace olFolderSentMail with 5.

Comment: Also, is Outlook running at the time your code is executed? Do you have "on error resume next" anywhere in your code? Get rid of that.

Comment: Yes, for the tools-->reference I checked the Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library. I replace the olFolderSentMail to 5, deleted all the on error resume next but now highlighted the set objItems and mentioned 'object doesnt support this propert or method'. Outlook is always running when I use my laptop.

Comment: If you are running in Excel VBA, the Application intrinsic variable points to Excel.Application, not Outlook.Application. Introduce new variable (objApp?), initialize it using set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"), and use objApp instead of Application.

Comment: I have added dim objApp as object and set set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"). In addition change the dim objItems as items and Set objItems = objApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items. It runs successfully but there is no email .msg in the local folder. Have edited above code as well.

Comment: Get rid of the "On Error Resume Next" line to see which line produces an error.

Comment: The think is there is no 'on error....' line inside my code. The code is running fine. however when out a pointer(use for debugging) at the classmodule, the codes didnt stop there. I am assuming the classmodule code is not running at all.

Comment: That line is just below the "With OutMail" line.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, forget to remove it here. But I removed it from the original file. It is still running fine but classmodule did not run at all.

Comment: Why are you adding the (draft) message to the Sent Items folder?

Comment: I dont get what you mean. I dont want to add the draft message to sent items folder. I want to save the sent message to our local drive folder.

Comment: But that it what your code does: Set objItems = objApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
Set OutMail = objItems.Add

Comment: I follow your instruction for that part. So it is not to do what I wanted to do? I really need your enlightenment.